# NHibernate associate class without pulling from repository

Tags: nhibernate

I'm sure I've done this before but I can't recall how.  I have 2 classes, say Person and Company.  I'm instantiating a new Person and want to set it up so that when I save it to repository it will be associated with Company A.  Company A already exists but I don't want to pull the entire thing from the DB just so I can write:

```
person.Company = CompanyA;
```

How can I set the Person's Company property so that it will be associated with CompanyA without pulling CompanyA from the DB?  I definitely don't want to map the CompanyID property btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ISession.Load(id)`. Ayende has a good post about [Get vs. Load](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/30/nhibernate-ndash-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by.aspx).

```
person.Company = session.Load(companyAId);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  Apparently I can't accept your answer for another 6 minutes, but I will when I can :).